# -webkit-box-shadow property not working in firefox

Tags: css

I'm having trouble with Firefox, my `CSS` code is:

```
#meni li:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 #FF0000;
}
```

It shows red shadow in Chrome, but in Firefox it doesn't work. Help anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include `-moz` prefix. `-webkit` is only used for webkit related browsers like Chrome/Safari.

```
#meni li:hover{
     opacity:1;
     filter:alpha(opacity=100);
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 #FF0000;
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 #FF0000;
     box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#meni li:hover{
box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 #FF0000;  /* use the standard, firefox doesn't need the prefix moz
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code like below :)

```
#meni li:hover{
         -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 #FF0000; /* for chrome and safari browser */
         -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 #FF0000;/* for mozilla browser */
         box-shadow: inset 0 4px 0 #FF0000; /*common*/
    }
```